# Child Theme Can't Find Parent In a Folder

Tags: child-theme

I am trying to make a child theme for a parent theme that is in a folder and it is not working. I tried to use: "Template: Parent Theme Folder Name" and that did not work. I tried the parent theme name all lower case and then Initial caps as it displays in the parent's style sheet and nothing works.

The parent theme was purchased and the entire folder was uploaded with the theme folder within the downloaded folder.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you uploaded the parent theme correctly? Are you able to activate the parent theme?

Comment: I tried downloading the folder and uploading just the theme folder and it works. Now I see that I loose all of the customizing work that was done.

Comment: Maybe because you did overwrite of files or you applied modifications to another theme, because according to your answer it seems that you uploaded any wrong folder earlier and when you upload the correct folder it started to work.

Comment: No, I downloaded the theme from the folder and uploaded it in the themes folder as well as my child theme an the original folder. After doing that, my child theme worked, but WordPress is not recognizing the new instance of the theme as the same theme and does not display the customization. I am giving up on making the child theme work. This commercial theme allows me to add css as one of the customization options, so I am adding my css there. Thanks for your response.